# GitHub with TeamManagement

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am beginner of git hub and I have a git hub account and create a public repository.Then add a team for that repository. A team member can't able to sync and can't able to commit on master branch it shows some error like "An error occurred. Detailed message: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Authorization Required)." how to resolve it?
(note:when use organization credentials(who create the repository) it will work.When i use as a team member credentials(github.com account)it will pass this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow a team member to push to the repository the team has to have `Write` or `Admin` permission on the repository. To edit permissions go to `Collaborators & Teams` in repository settings.

[image]

Furthermore ensure that the branch you want to push to is not protected. Branch protection can be managed under `Branches` in repository settings

Comment: @Tamilan you're welcome. If my answer correctly answered your question please rate it mark it as answer.

Comment: what is the purpose of checkout in branches (vs 2013) @rufer7

Comment: @Tamilan I don't know what you mean by "what is the purpose of checkout in branches (vs 2013)". It's not a GitHub specific question but a Git and Visual Studio 2013 specific one, correct? If yes, please consider the official git documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)